# R: Drawing markov model with diagram package (making diagram changes)

Tags: r, graph, markov

I have the following code that draws a transition probability graph using the package `heemod` (for the matrix) and the package `diagram` (for drawing). The following code generates such a graph with data that I have generated:

```
library('heemod')
library('diagram')
mat_dim <- define_transition(
state_names = c('State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C'),
  .18, .73, .09, 
  .12, .10, .78,
  .58, .08, .33);
plot(mat_dim)
```

This creates the following plot:

[image]

My questions all originate from my poor understanding of the `diagram` package and I can't figure out these seemingly simple adaptations...

How can I move the arrow at State_B around (e.g.90 degrees to one side) so that it does not overlap with other arrows? Is there a simple way to move the states closer together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `?plotmat`.

- argument `curve`, a matrix, to control the curvatures of the "non-self" transitions
- arguments `self.shiftx` and `self.shifty` to control the positions of the self-transitions
- argument `self.arrpos` to control the positions of the self-arrows

This is really not easy. Here is what I obtained by a lot of trial-errors.

```
curves <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 3, 0.05)
plot(mat_dim, 
     curve=curves, 
     self.shiftx = c(0.1,-0.1,0), 
     self.shifty = c(-0.1,-0.1,0.15), 
     self.arrpos = c(1,2.1,1))
```

[image]